# Excel Cell Staggering using Indirect functions

Tags: excel

I am creating a formula to read multiple sumif, certain values are > 0 across multiple excel sheets.  The formula works fine, but when I copy it to the right, the columns do not stagger by 1.

I realize this is a problem associated with the indirect function I used, but how do I get the columns to change to CU, CV etc?
Appreciate the help.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Exam2&"'!$d$2:$d$102"),">0",INDIRECT("'"&Exam2&"'!CT2:CT102"))/$D$105)
```

Comment: It might be helpful to have sample data and expected outcome

Comment: The idea is to have multiple columns with point values in them for multiple subjects that students are tested on.   If the function sees a column with a value > 0 in a certain column, then it adds the corresponding student column/row and produces an average for a certain point type (i.e. math, science, social studies).    I have to update the absolute values manually since I want it to look at specific columns.   I'm just trying to get the columns to stagger so I don't have to also update 20+ columns of students as I copy the function to the right (students each hae their own column).

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53051550/edit) instead of adding information in comments? You can then add a sample table, which will make it much easier to understand what you have and what end result your are looking for

Comment: Also, please use ``code` (notice the characters at each end - only one at each end) to *style* your code...